# Render nested list in vue without nesting HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, flexbox, v-for

I am in a bit of a problem cant think of way to solve neither could find anything relevant on google or rather I don't know what to search for.

I have an array `categories` and an object containing `subcategories`

```
categories: [
    'Mobiles',
    'Mobiles Accessories',
    ...
]

subcategories: {
    'Mobiles': [
        'Mi',
        'Samsung',
        'Infinix',
        ...
    ],
    'Mobile Accessories': [
        'Mobiles Cases',
        'Headphones & Earphones',
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now i want render a menu using that in following way.

```
<span class="category">Mobiles</span>
<span class="subcategory">Mi</span>
<span class="subcategory">Samsung</span>
<span class="subcategory">Infinix</span>
...
<span class="category">Mobile Accessories</span>
<span class="subcategory">Mobiles Cases</span>
<span class="subcategory">Headphones & Earphones</span>
...
```

If i use `v-for` in vue i will have to nest `.categories` and `.subcategories` inside a parent element for each `category`, which i don't want to do.

This whole mess is that i can use `flex-direction: column` in the parent element and when rendering the list, it automatically flows to next column which wont happen if i nest `.categories` and `.subcategories` in a parent element as now each parent element for `categories` will move to next column instead of its height.

So how can i achieve this either by changing `CSS` or the data structure.

Thanks
Akash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your question `Mobiles Accessories` does not equal `Mobile Accessories` so you have to make sure the categories array contains the exaxt names of the keys in subcategories.

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const categories = ['Mobiles', 'Mobile Accessories'];

const subcategories = {
    Mobiles: ['Mi', 'Samsung', 'Infinix'],
    'Mobile Accessories': ['Mobiles Cases', 'Headphones & Earphones'],
};

console.log(
    categories.reduce(
        (result, value) =>
            result.concat(
                { class: 'category', value },
                subcategories[value].map((value) => ({
                    class: 'subcategory',
                    value,
                })),
            ),
        [],
    ),
);
```

Comment: Purrrfect ... never thought of doing that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution for You!!!

Using two for loops you can do this.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    menu: {
      categories:[
      'Accessories',
     'Mobiles',
     ],
    subcategories: {
       'Accessories': [
        'Mobiles Cases',
        'Headphones & Earphones',        
    ],
    'Mobiles': [
        'Mi',
        'Samsung',
        'Infinix'
    ],
   
}
  }
  }
});
```

```css
.category{
display:block;
padding:10px 0px;
}
.subcategory{
display:block:
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(menus,index) in menu.categories">
      <span class="category">{{ menus }}</span>
        <span class="subcategory" v-for="(submenu,index) in menu.subcategories[menus]">{{submenu}}<br/></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me know if problem.

Comment: No this doesn't solve the problem as for each category, there is parent category block which contains all the subcategories. I want the categories and subcategories to have same parent yet keep them in ordered.